# How to disable systemd timers "Succeeded" messages

Tags: systemd

Every 30 minutes we get a
`Dec 10 02:09:00 fileserver systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.`
message. We use logcheck to get an email when there is something in the log, but now after we updated to debian 10 we get an email every hour because of these `phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.` messages. Is there a way to disable this messages?

I added `LogLevelMax=alert` to the `[Service]` section of the `/lib/systemd/system/phpsessionclean.service` file, but this didn't helped.

Answer (score 2):

I have not found out how to disable the messages. But you can filter the message out with logcheck. We use the loglevel "workstation", so I have created the file `/etc/logcheck/ignore.d.workstation/systemd` with the content

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ (systemd)\[[[:digit:]]+\]: [a-z]+\.service: Succeeded\.$
```

to ignore the `Jan  9 20:39:01 servername systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.` messages.

Comment: Some useful Regex snippets: https://wiki.bluelightav.org/display/BLUE/Logcheck+administration#Logcheckadministration-Howdoeslogcheckwork?